# C++ Programm crashes only in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've trouble with my application. Every time I launch it in the debugger it crashes when adding an item to a map. When I start it as standalone app it works properly.

The Objekt which has the map is deleted and recreated, and after the recreation the debugger crashes with an error and the whole pc is frozen. The only way is do a hard restart.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

P.s.: This is the relevant code snippet:

Header:

```
        /**
         * List of      propertyKey     value
         */
        typedef std::map<std::string, boost::any>   Changes;
        /**
         * List of       id          changes
         */
        typedef std::map<std::string, Changes>      ChangesMap;
     ChangesMap                             m_changeList;
```

Methodbody:

```
void PushController::CollectAttributeChanges(
    const std::string &id, const std::string &key, const boost::any &value)
{
    (m_changeList[id])[key] = value;
}
```

Best regards,
Gerrit

Comment: *When I start it as standalone app it works properly.* --- are you 100% sure about that? An undefined behaviour can cause the program to appear to run properly.

Comment: you said "debugger crashes with an error", can you add the error? Does it create a dump file?

Comment: When you start a program under debugger a special heap is used, so behavior can be different from when you start the program on its own.

Comment: On what line exactly does the crash occur? Can you run your "standalone app" through valgrind?

Answer (score 1):

Have you built your app with any flags that can affect the STL binary compatibility in some way (e.g. _SECURE_SCL=0) and is boost built in the same way?

Could another part of the application be corrupting the heap?

You can insert _CrtCheckMemory() calls throughout your code to detect heap corruptions closer to when they occurred.